# How can I calculate earned value in MS Project with variable costs?

Tags: ms-project, pm-software, budget, learning

I'm using MS Project to manage training projects as a vendor. We are currently calculating earned value based on the hours budget for deliverables. However, we often have multiple people on the project at different billable rates, and also sell some deliverables in units instead of hours - training deliveries are a good example.

I'm looking for a simple way to more accurately calculate the earned value based on dollars instead of hours; any ideas?

Is there a column I could include with costs? How would that correspond to Work, and what % Complete field would I use? If I apply a billable rate to Resources am I creating a lot of work for myself just managing the software? What else haven't I thought of yet?

Thanks!

Comment: You are essentially asking how to do earned value. You can do the math using hours but it is because of the variability in costs that you are supposed to do it using dollars.  It is after all a cost control tool, not an hours control tool.

Answer (score 1):

You should assign resources to the tasks, and the resources have their rates. That should not bee too much of work for you.

MSP then calculates all the components. For Actual costs, you can override the calculations.

If MSP is too cumbersome to use in this context, you should revert to good old Excel (and maybe interconnect those two)

Answer (score 0):

Can you estimate the value of the work package?   Then you can track the costs against the value earned.